# Why can't I compare char to "*"?

Tags: c++

Why can't I compare `UserInput[i]` to `"*"` ? The compiler says "ISO c++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer". Where is the integer? The only one I see on that line is `i`, which is used for locating the specific character.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char UserInput[4] = "2*3";
    for (int i=0; i< strlen(UserInput); i++)
    {
        if(UserInput[i] == "*")
        {
            cout<<"There is multiplication Involved \n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use C-style strings. `std::string` is your friend.

Comment: This indentation is just... nasty.

Answer (score 5):

> Where is the integer?

Your conditional expression is `UserInput[i] == "*"`.

In the expression `UserInput[i]` is of type `char`. In many of the binary operations, `char` is promoted to `int` before the operation is carried out. As far as the compiler is concerned, it is comparing an `int` with `"*"`, which is of type `const char[2]` but decays to a pointer in the expression.

What you need to do is compare the `char` with the character constant `'*'`. Use

```
if(UserInput[i] == '*') {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(UserInput[i] == "*")
```

> Will issue a warning  because of ""

`"*"` is not char. `"*"` is a `const char*`.

Comparison between pointer and integer (`int` and `const char *`) is not possible

change it to

```
if(UserInput[i] == '*')
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, use `std::string` instead of char arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string UserInput = "2*3";
    for (int i = 0; i < UserInput.length(); i++) {
        if (UserInput[i] == '*') {
            cout << "There is multiplication Involved \n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit tricky.
All inside  **"** **"** is a string - array of chars. Array in c/c++ is pointer to first element of array.
Each single element of string is char, which is converted to int.
At the end, compiler says that it's not possible to compare this two items.
You need to do like this:

```
if(UserInput[i] == '*')
```

In this case you compare two chars with no problem.

**PS** If you want to determine presence of one string in another string, you should use [`strstr()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/).

Comment: why this     strncpy (pch,"sample",6); example is required?